# Giving the user some information on the run status of my program

Tags: user-interface, racket

I made a simple GUI for my Racket batch data processing program that accepts a user specified input file and writes to a user specified output file.  Once the user has specified those files, all they have to do is click a "Run" button.  The program works, but the GUI becomes unresponsive while running the batch processing logic. Since it can take a long time to finish, I want to give the user some assurance that it hasn't crashed.  How can I avoid this unresponsiveness (at least the frozen window part)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the batch processing in a thread.

See [Racket docs on thread](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/threads.html?q=thread#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._thread%29%29)

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like the right solution. I tried wrapping my processing function in `(thread (processing-function in-file out-file))` and the code ran as before, but Windows labeled the gui as "Not Responding" this time.

Comment: You need to give thread a thunk. Use `(thread (lambda () (processing-function in-file out-file)))`.